# IF else converting to and or in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I am converting this query

```
WHERE (Worksheet.ProjectId = ' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @ProjectId) + ')

    IF(@StatusTypeId IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @WhereClause = ' AND StatusType.StatusTypeId IS NULL'
    END
    ELSE IF (@StatusTypeId > 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @WhereClause = ' AND StatusType.StatusTypeId = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @StatusTypeId)
    END
```

with this

```
WHERE Worksheet.ProjectId = @ProjectId
AND
((@StatusTypeId IS NULL AND StatusType.StatusTypeId IS NULL)
OR (@StatusTypeId > 0 AND StatusType.StatusTypeId = @StatusTypeId))
```

What is wrong with this. when i give only @ProjectId then it gives me no row it show show me records but it works fine when i give both parameters values means projectId and statusTypeId.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code...

```
IF(@StatusTypeId IS NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @WhereClause = ' AND StatusType.StatusTypeId IS NULL'
END
```

..has an implicit ELSE

```
ELSE --@StatusTypeId IS NOT NULL
    SET ... is something always true because no condition dynamically added
```

You missed this implied "something always true for @StatusTypeId IS NOT NULL"

The same applies to the other condition too

```
WHERE Worksheet.ProjectId = @ProjectId
AND
(
  (@StatusTypeId IS NOT NULL OR
         (@StatusTypeId IS NULL AND StatusType.StatusTypeId IS NULL)
  )
  OR
  (@StatusTypeId <= 0 OR
         (@StatusTypeId > 0 AND StatusType.StatusTypeId = @StatusTypeId)
  )
)
```

Comment: @Sami: Please upvote and/or accept then (the up arrow and tick on the left). In the FAQ: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/27535